# SQL Server DATEDIFF Function get wrong Values

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

This function bring wrong values

```
select DATEDIFF(MONTH,'09-01-2014','08-31-2016')
Result:23
it must be :24

select DATEDIFF(MONTH,'01-01-2014','08-31-2016')
Result:31
it must be :32

select DATEDIFF(MONTH,'07-01-2013','06-30-2016')
Result:35
it must be :36
```

Is it wrong or I missed somthing ??
any way to solve this problem ?

Comment: . . In the last case, I assume you are looking for 36 and not 37.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are missing what `datediff()` really does.  It measures the number of times that "boundaries" between dates parts are crossed.  That means the difference (in months) between 2014-01-01 and 2014-01-31 is `0`.  The difference between 2014-01-31 and 2014-02-01 is `1`.

The [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189794%28v=sql.100%29.aspx) is not shy about this behavior.  It starts:

> Returns the count (signed integer) of the specified datepart
>   boundaries crossed between the specified startdate and enddate.

EDIT:

For the examples you give in your question, you can add one day to the final date:

```
select DATEDIFF(MONTH, '2014-09-01', dateadd(day, 1, '2016-08-31'))
```

I don't know if this is a general solution to your problem.

Comment: understood thank you , but what should I do to bring the values that I need ??
any way to solve this in this case ??

Comment: The last case bring 35 and it must be 37 so +1 will not solve all cases